# Is there any difference between CIDR & VLSM?

Tags: networking

As I understand it, the terms **Classless Inter-Domain Routing (CIDR)** and **Variable-Length Subnet Masking (VLSM)** effectively refer to the same thing.  Is there any noteworthy difference between the proper definitions of these terms?  What is the history or relation between the two?

Answer (score 1):

read this [How does IPv4 Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work)

I believe it is explain in one of the answers there.

Comment: yes indeed, it is there for certain, hopefully that sets you straight.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but could you actually include the appropriate content in your answer?